# Pie chart in p5.js

Tags: javascript, draw, trigonometry, pie-chart, p5.js

I am trying to create a pie chart in javascript using p5js however I am having difficulty figuring out how to draw the start and end position of the different pie 'chunks' using % values. could someone please give me an example of a arc that is 20% of a full circle and what calculations I need to do to figure it out for myself?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's a bit harsh to get downvotes and close votes immediately, however that is because the current form of your question is phrased as if you want people to write code for you without you showing your attempt as a minimal example highlighting the specific part you're struggling with. Please rephrase your question taking these points into account. You might also find this question and answer relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660637/how-to-identify-the-cursor-within-an-arc-in-p5-js/68664686#68664686 .

Comment: Take a minute to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge. It should give an idea of how this site works differently from forums.

Answer (score 1):

Change the example to: let angles = [72, 324];

72 is 20% of 360 degrees.

https://p5js.org/examples/form-pie-chart.html

Answer (score 1):

The degrees are typically measured in Radians, but you can change it to degrees using `angleMode(degrees)` 20% of a 360-degree circle is 72. So you could use the following code

`angleMode(degrees)`

`arc(Xposition,Yposition,Width,Height,0,72)`